# How to declare TypeScript type of function that returns own prototype?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write type definitions that would cause the following code to type-check:

```js
// MyThing becomes the prototype, but can't be created with `new`
const created = MyThing("hello");

// inferred type of `created` should make `takeAction` be available
created.takeAction();

function sampleFunction(arg: string | MyThing) {
    if (arg instanceof MyThing) {
        // instanceof check should make `takeAction` be available
        arg.takeAction();
    }
}

sampleFunction(created);
```

So far, I've tried this:

```js
interface MyThing {
    takeAction(): void;
}

declare function MyThing(id: string): MyThing;
```

That works, except that `instanceof` doesn't narrow the type correctly. I also tried this:

```js
declare class MyThing {
    constructor(id: string);
    takeAction(): void;
}
```

However, that causes an error on the line where `created` is declared, as a `class` can't be made callable. I also tried a few variations of type merging to add a call interface to a declared `MyThing` class, but that didn't work either: In each case I get this error message:

```
Value of type 'typeof MyThing' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
```

Unfortunately, I'm trying to describe an existing codebase, so requiring `new MyThing` isn't an option.

Is there a way to correctly declare the type of `MyThing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a note out of the standard library which declares Array like the following:

```js
interface Array<T> {
    length: number;
    //...
}
interface ArrayConstructor {
    // ...
    new <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    readonly prototype: Array<any>;
}

declare const Array: ArrayConstructor;
```

We can declare `MyThing` as:

```js
interface MyThing {
    takeAction(): void;
}
interface MyThingConstructor {
    readonly prototype: MyThing;
    (id: string): MyThing;
}
declare const MyThing: MyThingConstructor;
```

Comment: Thank you: That did exactly what I needed.